# No Of Divisors of a number having atleast one common digit with the given number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers

As Question says.I need to count the number of Divisors of a given number say x. But the constraint is that the divisor must have atleast one digit common with given number x.

Say for 10 answer would be 2. (1,10,2,5 are the divisors but only 1,10 share the same digits with 10)

Comment: @all it is not a homework..It is a programming question on a programming portal.. given that x can be as large as 10^9.. brute force would not work..

Comment: What's wrong with the easy solution? Step 1: get all divisors. Step 2: check each one to see if it has common digits. Worst-case complexity can't be worse than the best available method, since both need to work on the number 9876543210.

Comment: It sounds like you wanting us to do it for you. Honestly, there's not any question, just a list of requirements.

Comment: what have you tried, first try and then post the code to check if a better answer exists.

Comment: guys to be honest don't u think brute force would take too much of time for no say 10^9.. writing brute force code would be child's play for this problem.

Comment: @Algorithmist: Then write the brute force and ask us questions of how to improve your implementation.

Comment: For the record, my C# brute force will find that the number 9876543210 has 72 divisors that meet these requirements in 156568ms (just under 3 mins). A better number might make for a better test though... one without every possible digit in it.

Comment: Reran it with the number 9955687758 getting 12 at 157094ms (again, under 3 mins)

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - Silly. Why would it take 3 minutes to do anything like that? First, factor the number.  9955687758 = 2x3x31x53525203. Then listing the unique divisors is trivial, truly milliseconds work, both to factor it and to find the divisors. {1, 2, 3, 6, 31, 62, 93, 186, 53525203, 107050406, 160575609, 321151218, 1659281293, 3318562586, 4977843879, 9955687758}.
Testing the digits is yet another work of tiny fractions of a second, not minutes, and this is what I'd describe as brute force.

Comment: I think it's my inefficient finding of divisors. My approach is very similar to how A.R.S. did his, although I used LINQ for determining if the common digit existed.

Comment: I was wondering that. If you do trial divides by all of the numbers less than N, this will take time. Slightly better is to do trial divides by all integers less than sqrt(N). This must expose ALL divisors, since if a is a divisor, then we must have found a pair of divisors, N = a*b. floor(sqrt(9955687758)) = 99778, so there are less than 100k trial divides needed, still far less than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
private static boolean containCommonDigit(int n1, int n2) {
    for (char c : ("" + n1).toCharArray())
        if (("" + n2).contains("" + c))
            return true;
    return false;
}

public static int countSpecialDivisors(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= n / 2 ; i++)
        if (n % i == 0 && containCommonDigit(n, i))
            count++;
    return count + 1;  // since we are looping to n/2
}
```

Notice that we are only looping to `n/2` since we know that `n` will have no divisors greater than half of itself besides itself, which explains why we add 1 at the end (obviously, `n` shares at least one common digit with itself).

See the comments for ideas regarding further optimizations.

Comment: it is better to have the loop run n/2 times, don't you think?

Comment: Yes good idea, I edited the answer above

Comment: hey, to make it work faster loop it till sqr(n) and then the below code can be used `if(n % i == 0){if(containCommonDigit(n, i)) count++; if(containCommonDigit(n, n/i))count++;}` and also we don't need to increament the counter at last line

Comment: Good idea again - I'll let the OP deal with any further optimizations, as long as he has a general idea of how the code above works.

Comment: What's the running time? As poorly as the question was asked, I am curious of the answer.

Comment: sqrt works well for finding prime numbers, but doesn't work for regular ones. For example, sqrt(n) will miss divisor 5 of number 10

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to find all divisors for the number, it might be tricky - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

2) next, given by the number and it'sdivisor - you need to extract all digits, it's simple - just get remainder of division by 10 and proceed with fraction part. Put digits into Set

3) use removeAll on the sets, and if set changed - then there are common numbers

repeat steps 2/3 with next divisor you found.

Comment: i don't think divisor function gives the algo to get all the divisors, it just defines some properties of the divisors

Comment: @AnkurMittal I didn't state it will give all divisors, just illustrate what properties might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this.

```
 public String (int numberToBeFactored){
      String result = "1, ";

      for(int i = 2; i < numberToBeFactored){
           if (numberToBeFactored % i == 0){
               result = result + Integer.toString(i) + ", ";
           }
       }
       result.trim();
       return result; 

   }
```